# Doing curl POST request as an npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a new script in my npm scripts in my `package.json` and the single quotes/double quotes are causing this to break. Namely the internal double quotes inside of the payload

`"slack": "curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#builds", "text": "New Build Incoming!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/abc/123/00000",`

Any tips on how to get this working?

Answer (score 5):

Just use \ before double quotes

```
"slack": "curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={\"channel\": \"#builds\", \"text\": \"New Build Incoming!\"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/abc/123/00000",
```